# How to sort words of a sequence by a specific pattern

Tags: python

So basically I need to sort the words from the first string to match with second string's order.

```
def sort_string_by_specific_pattern(self, initial_string, expected_string):
    #Remove punctuation from strings
    initial_string = str(initial_string).translate(None, 
           string.punctuation)
    expected_string = str(expected_string).translate(None, 
           string.punctuation)

    new_sorted_string = " "  #we need spaces between words

    # map sentences to integer location
    spitted = expected_string.split()
    d_map = {w: [i for i in range(len(spitted)) if spitted[i] == w]
                for w in set(spitted)}

    initial_string = initial_string.split()

    # sort by calculated location mapping
    extracted_sorted = sorted(initial_string, key=d_map.get)
    new_sorted_string = str(new_sorted_string.join(extracted_sorted))
    return [new_sorted_string, expected_string ]
```

For example:

```
initial_string= 'apple one and two apple'

expected_string= 'apple one and apple two'
```

I want to make the initial_string to look exactly like the expected_string but the main problem is with the duplicate word 'apple'.

What I have done so far :
I have a **dictionary** that keeps as keys = words from the expected string and for values = index of the word location in the string

```
d_map= {'and': [2], 'one': [1], 'apple': [0, 4], 'two': [3]}
```

But when I sort the initial string by this dictionary `sorted(initial_string, key=d_map.get)` the result is:

```
`new_sorted_string= 'apple apple one and two'`
```

instead of

```
new_sorted_string= 'apple one and apple two'
```

Comment: What happens when the words from two strings are different? Can you provide an example in that case?

Comment: What is your problem with duplicate words ? Do you need to keep only one 'apple' in your sorted string list ?

Comment: @RockyLi if the words from strings are different I don't want anything to happen in that case.

Comment: @m.raynal my problem with the duplicate words is that I want to sort the first string based on the second one and I want to keep both 'apple' from the string.             I want to make the initial_string                                                                     from-->  'apple one and two apple'                                                                     to-->      'apple one and apple two'    exactly like the expected_string.

Comment: Can I ask _why_? If the words are different you don't want to do anything, so surely just check the bag of words between the two strings is the same, then return the second string if it is?

Comment: I don't quite get what it's meant to do. It tries to identify a pattern from an expected string to give out the expected string? Snark aside, if you want it to look "exactly" like it you can just echo it, since you already have it... this needs some clearing up if you want a good answer. We could easily get into formal grammar implementation to identify the rules if there's a good reason to.

Comment: @KenSyme I want to return the initial_string after I sorted it exactly like the expected_string just to see if I can sort the words in the same order

Comment: @lucasgcb the main reason why I am doing this is because I want to verify if a text is equal with another one (but in the second one the words are changing their order frequently) and I don’t want to check if if the words are equals , I want to check the entire sentence. Thank you 

Comment: Still not sure it's clear what you are doing and why - doing it as an exercise to show you can is quite artificial, and if you want to check the text is equal, where you don't care about the order of words, can easily do that by comparing the words and their frequency.  _"don’t want to check if if the words are equals , I want to check the entire sentence"_ - why make it more complicated??

Comment: @KenSyme Yes, I know is more complicated like that and maybe is a waste of time creating this function witch could be easily done by checking the words but I wanted a more complex way and now I want to finish what I started

Comment: @RuxiIerima Okay, so is this thing you want to do sorting or comparison? Is sorting the way you are doing comparisons? Because if you want to compare whole sentences you can do `sentence1 == sentence2`... this is coming across as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @lucasgcb I want just to sort the words from the first string to match with the second one :)

Comment: @RuxiIerima You want to extract a whole pattern off a single sequence of words and apply it to a similar sequence (same elements, wrong arbitrarily defined "order") in the hopes that you'll get the original sequence. Well, are your sentences gibberish? Italian? You'll need to define rules to do any sort of word sorting because the pattern is dependent entirely on how well the sentences fit with the rules and even then you'll still have some margin of error which needs treatment. I'd recommend reading up on formal languages and doing smaller tasks rather than doing this.